# Printing on local printer from web application with limitations

Tags: asp.net, printing

I need to develop application, witch fetch data from some databases, compose document and then print it on local (label) printer.

It would be nice, if main application can be web based (ASP.NET). But I need control on the printing process to do not allow users to print the same document again.

Can you suggest me some solution? It is possible to create desktop application also, but we prefer web application.

One idea I have had was to implement some custom protocol as netmeeting does (callto://), but I don't know, if it is good idea and how difficult it would be.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized this as I write by custom protocol (callto://) and I can recommend it. Protocol opens simple desktop application (it can be set up in windows registry) configured to print data fetched data to local printer.

In the protocol link a have base64 encoded url of webservice to ask for data and session id with customized print request for generating print data.

Works fine.